# How to have infinite number of copy to clipboard for infinite elements that have same class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, copy, clipboard

My HTML:

```
   <Div Class='POSTS'>
    <Div Class='POST'>
        <Div Class='CONTENT'>Text1</Div>
    </Div>
    <Div Class='POST'>
        <Div Class='CONTENT'>Text2</Div>
    </Div>
    <Div Class='POST'>
        <Div Class='CONTENT'>Text3</Div>
    </Div>
    <Div Class='POST'>
        <Div Class='CONTENT'>Text4</Div>
    </Div>
    <Div Class='POST'>
        <Div Class='CONTENT'>Text5</Div>
    </Div>
    <Div Class='POST'>
        <Div Class='CONTENT'>Text6</Div>
    </Div>
</Div>
```

And It Continues Without Any Limit...(Never Ending)
With Different Text Inside Each Element With Class Of "CONTENT".

I Searched Over This Website And Found This :

Https://Stackoverflow.Com/Questions/400212/How-Do-I-Copy-To-The-Clipboard-In-Javascript

But In The Project That I'm Working In I Can't Specify Id On Each Element As You Know It's Infinite Number Of These Elements:

```
<Div Class='POST'>
        <Div Class='CONTENT'>some text</Div>
    </Div>
```

So It Needs To Be Automatically Added.

And I Want To :
When User Clicks On The Text Inside Of Element With The Class Of "CONTENT" (No Matter How Long The Text Is And What It Have) , The Entire Text And Tags And ... Be Copied To Clipbored.

I Don't Want To Set Buttons !
I Want To Make The Whole

Tags,Text,And ....
Be Copied On Each One Of Them Without Any Limits!
By Clicking on it's own text.(imagine this as a textarea that user clicks on text inside of it and js copies all of text but this one is div with text inside of it)

If You Think I Missed Sth And It's Not Clear Enough Let Me Know!

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.
First select the entire object and then get the element which was clicked. Copy the content.

```
var posts = document.querySelector(".POSTS"); 

posts
  .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log("index", e.target);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.target.innerText).then(
      function () {
        console.log("Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!");
      },
      function (err) {
        console.error("Async: Could not copy text: ", err);
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: exactly:) Thanks Man!

Comment: You can check for navigator.clipboard object before the execution. Otherwise you'll have to write a fallback.